# How to calculate difference MySQL date in PHP?

Tags: php, mysql

I try lots of things but I can not find the solution.

```
$con=mysqli_connect('localhost','root','root','hidroist');
if(! $con)
    echo "Error" . mysqli_error($con);
$maxresult = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT MAX(var) as 'max' FROM date");
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($maxresult);
echo $row['max'];

 $minresult = mysqli_query($baglanti, "SELECT min(var) as 'min' FROM date;");
 $row = mysqli_fetch_array($minresult);
 echo "<br>";
 echo $row['min'];
 echo "<br>";
```

I need to calculate difference between $row['min'] and $row['max'] after that database should delete all data from table .

Comment: Hello, please list the 'lot of things' that you have tried or better describe what you want to achieve. Currently this question is unclear

Comment: Going by the vague explanation, I'm not even sure that a database is a good fit for this.

Comment: $start = strtotime($row['min']);
$end = strtotime($row['max']);
$difference= abs($end- $star);
$result=getdate($difference); 
echo ("$sonuc[minutes]");          or php date diff function

Comment: I need a database to take data from gsm module and database should take current time that data sending from module.I am new at this

Answer (score 0):

you coudl do this with a single query  and use backtics for  reserver or keyword  or column name alis and  not single quote

```
$allresult = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT MAX(var) as `max` ,
         min(var) as `min` , MAX(var) - min(var) as my_diff FROM date");
```

for my this you can access to the value using the same alias name  eg as in you code using $row

```
     echo $row['my_diff'];
```

Comment: How can I print my_diff?